# How to best flatten NDJson data in Python

Tags: python, ndjson

I have a huge file (>400MB) of NDJson formatted data and like to flatten it into a table format for further analysis.

I started iterate through the various objects manually but some are rather deep and might even change over time, so I was hoping for a more general approach.

I was certain pandas lib would offer something but could not find anything that would help my case. Also, the several other libs I found seem to not ‘fully’ provide what I was hoping for (flatten_json). It all seems very early on.

Is it possible that there is not good (fast and easy) solve for this at this time?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Just a suggestion: whenever I need to analyse JSON data I tend to stick them in a database. If the structure is known I go with SQLite+SQLAlchemy. Alternatively, there are lots of noSQL object-based databases that you can use to store and analyse/explore such file. However, with this approach you always need one "ingest" script and one or more analysis scripts...

Comment: Thanks for the response but I was really hoping to get it done using pandas dataframe. Definitely don't want to introduce a DB at this time.

Answer (score 2):

pandas `read_json` has a bool param `lines`, set this to True to read ndjsons

`data_frame = pd.read_json('ndjson_file.json', lines=True)`